# Proving that $\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{N+k}$ approaches $ln(2)$ as $N$ approaches infinity

Tags: real-analysis

I have the feeling of being stuck or missing something trying to prove
$$ \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{N+k} =\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x} dx = ln(2)$$

Using Riemann-Sums I have shown that $$\int_{1}^{a} \frac{1}{x} dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N} (a^{1/N}-1)=\lim_{N\to\infty}N(a^{1/N}-1)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=ln(a)$$

So I would have to show that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{N+k}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N} (2^{1/N}-1)$$

However the summands are not equal. How does one prove this equality?

Comment: Well, when I compute the $N$-th Riemann sum of $\int_1^2\frac 1 x\,dx$, then I get exactly the sum that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prove those sums are equal by showing $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{N+k} = \ln(2)$$ in a different way. Note $$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{N+k} = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{N}}\frac{1}{N}$$ which is a Riemann-sum and thus converges to $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x} = \ln(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{N + k} = \lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{1}{1 + \tfrac{k}{N}} - \frac{1}{N}\right) = \int_1^2\frac{1}{x}dx.$$

Comment: You should correct your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to take the partitions $P_N$ of $[1,2]$ given by

$P_N=\left \{1,1+1/N,\cdots, 1+\frac{N-1}{N},2  \right \}$ and consider the (lower) Riemann sum corresponding to $P_N:$

$L(f,P_N)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{N}}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{N+k}.$

As $f(x)=1/x$ is Riemann-integral on $[1,2],$ if $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $P$ is $any$ evenly-spaced partition such that $\Delta x_i<\delta$ then $\left | \int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x} -L(P,f) \right|<\epsilon.$

Thus, as soon as $1/N<\delta,$ we have $\left | \int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x} - \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{N+k}\right|<\epsilon.$

The result now follows because $\int^2_1\frac{dx}{x}=\ln2.$